# Mobile app with Spring backend

Tags: reactjs, authentication, spring-boot, react-native, backend

I'm developing a Spring Boot project to serve a web site and a mobile app.
The web site is developed using ReactJS and the mobile app uses React Native.
My concern is how the mobile app will communicate with the back end:

1. Do I need to write 2 different APIs? one for the web site that uses Spring Security and a second one for the mobile app?
2. How can I handle authentication for the mobile app? Does it work with Spring Security also?
3. What is the best way to design a secured backend to serve a website as well as a mobile app?

I have developed a web app using Spring boot as a backend and ReactJS as front end.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I have deloped a solution similar than you are implementing, your answers.

**1. Do I need to write 2 different APIs? one for the web site that uses Spring Security and a second one for the mobile app?**
No, you can implement one Rest API and it can be used for both. If the same user can authenticate in web and mobil, it must be the same rest api.

**2. How can I handle authentication for the mobile app? Does it work with Spring Security also?**
Both, web and mobile have to use JWT, it is a token, you implement the backend with Spring Security, it supports JWT implementation and your web and mobile will work equals.

**3. What is the best way to design a secured backend to serve a website as well as a mobile app?**
You need to implement two diferent projects, web and mobile, but you can do some libraries or tools to run in both, web and mobile. About the security you can use JWT, it will work with all security features of Spring Security.

Read more about this:
https://jwt.io/introduction/